# Error for cv::FileStorage in JNI

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk, file-storage

I am getting errors while compiling my native.cpp file in Eclipse ADT/NDK.

While compiling the following lines of code

```
FileStorage storage(nativepath, FileStorage::WRITE);
storage << "img" << mat;
storage.release();
```

The errors are

> D:/androidworkspace/Augmented-Reality//obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/ndksetup/native.o:
>   In function
>   `Java_com_shahrukh_AugmentedReality_CAMShiftDetection_savemat(_JNIEnv*,
>   _jobject*, long long, _jstring*)': D:\androidworkspace\Augmented-Reality/jni/native.cpp:14: undefined
>   reference to`cv::FileStorage::FileStorage(std::string const&, int,
>   std::string const&)'
>   D:/androidworkspace/Augmented-Reality//obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/ndksetup/native.o:
>   In function `operator<<':
>   D:/android-development/OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk/OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include/opencv2/core/operations.hpp:2923:
>   undefined reference to`cv::operator<<(cv::FileStorage&, std::string
>   const&)'
>   D:/androidworkspace/Augmented-Reality//obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/ndksetup/native.o:
>   In function `operator<< <cv::Mat>':
>   D:/android-development/OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk/OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include/opencv2/core/operations.hpp:2914:
>   undefined reference to`cv::write(cv::FileStorage&, std::string
>   const&, cv::Mat const&)'
>   D:/androidworkspace/Augmented-Reality//obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/ndksetup/native.o:
>   In function
>   `Java_com_shahrukh_AugmentedReality_CAMShiftDetection_savemat(_JNIEnv*,
>   _jobject*, long long, _jstring*)': D:\androidworkspace\Augmented-Reality/jni/native.cpp:16: undefined
>   reference to`cv::FileStorage::release()'
>   D:\androidworkspace\Augmented-Reality/jni/native.cpp:18: undefined
>   reference to `cv::FileStorage::~FileStorage()'
>   D:/androidworkspace/Augmented-Reality//obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/ndksetup/native.o:
>   In function`operator<< ':
>   D:/android-development/OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk/OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include/opencv2/core/operations.hpp:2913:
>   undefined reference to `cv::Exception::Exception(int, std::string
>   const&, std::string const&, std::string const&, int)'
>   D:/android-development/OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk/OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include/opencv2/core/operations.hpp:2913:
>   undefined reference to`cv::error(cv::Exception const&)'
>   D:/android-development/OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk/OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include/opencv2/core/operations.hpp:2913:
>   undefined reference to `cv::Exception::~Exception()'
>   D:/android-development/OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk/OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include/opencv2/core/operations.hpp:2913:
>   undefined reference to`cv::Exception::~Exception()'
>   D:/androidworkspace/Augmented-Reality//obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/ndksetup/native.o:
>   In function
>   `Java_com_shahrukh_AugmentedReality_CAMShiftDetection_savemat(_JNIEnv*,
>   _jobject*, long long, _jstring*)': D:\androidworkspace\Augmented-Reality/jni/native.cpp:18: undefined
>   reference to`cv::FileStorage::~FileStorage()' collect2.exe: error: ld
>   returned 1 exit status make.exe: ***
>   [D:/androidworkspace/Augmented-Reality//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libndksetup.so]
>   Error 1

This is my `native.cpp` file

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>

using namespace cv;

JNIEXPORT void Java_com_shahrukh_AugmentedReality_CAMShiftDetection_savemat(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj,jlong addrmat, jstring path)
{
    const char *nativepath = env->GetStringUTFChars(path, 0);
    Mat& mat = *(Mat*)addrmat;

    FileStorage storage(nativepath, FileStorage::WRITE);
    storage << "img" << mat;
    storage.release();

    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(path, nativepath);
}
```

This is my `Android.mk` File

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

export OPENCV_PACKAGE_DIR = D:/android-development/OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk/OpenCV-2.4.10-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=off
include $(OPENCV_PACKAGE_DIR)/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -ldl

LOCAL_MODULE    := ndksetup
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := native.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

This is my `Application.mk`

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := all
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of debugging I found that the error was quite small

The error was in the line

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -ldl
```

The line should have been

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog -ldl
```